# NullPointerException when Starting Glassfish 4.0 in Eclipse on OSX Mavericks

Tags: eclipse, osx-mavericks, glassfish-4

I am using Mac 10.9 OSX Mavericks and Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers(kepler).

I've installed Glassfish 4.0 using the 'new server' option in eclipse and the latest JDK - Java SE 7 [1.7.0_55].

but when trying to start the server, I get this error -

An internal error occurred during: "Starting GlassFish 4.0 at localhost".
java.lang.NullPointerException

Is there anything wrong with my setup? Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: A stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: There are no projects added to the server. It is just an empty server and I am getting the error when starting.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open eclipse.ini file which is located in your eclipse installation directory (in the same folder with eclipse.exe).
2. Add -Duser.language=en in the bottom of your eclipse.ini.
3. Restart eclipse.

Comment: This one worked for me. How did you know what to do? What is really funny, Glassfish 3.1 stopped to work. With the same NPE exception.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers(juno) instead of kepler and it works!

I am not sure what the problem with kepler is but this is a solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while using Windows 8.1, jdk1.8.0_20, & Eclipse Luna.

I deleted the glassfish server, then re-installed, and it was all fine!

Note:

Remember to delete the server from the installation location.

Also in eclipse when you do a new installation, remember to go to "Configure Runtime Variable" (In the New Server Window), delete the existing config for Glassfish. then when you click next you will be prompted to select the JDK where you can select the correct version of the JDK. If you don't see the correct version of the jdk or no jdk version at all, then you will find above JDK a link called "Installed JRE Preferences"  add the right version from there!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Win7,jdk1.7.0_67, Eclipse Luna, glassfish 4.

As I suspected there is something wrong with the JDK settings, so I checked the Servers config in Preferences and in runtime environments my glassfish server got the problem: invalid JRE.

So I tried to set the JDK but the Finish button just isn't working.
I deleted that server and created a new with the same settings, and it's working.
I'm not sure though what caused this problem.